# Display more than one search result on Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem when I want to search in multidimensional arrays.
I have a string inside the textarea

```
<textarea id='alltemplatememe'>
    ['2','makan lagi','kwik-templatememe-20171208215155.jpg'],['1','apapun','kwik-templatememe-20171208215124.jpg']
</textarea>
```

and i will change the data in textarea into array, such as the function below

```
function meme_template_search(){
    var keyword=$("#keyword_template").val();
    var template=$("#alltemplatememe").val();
    var resultsame="";
    template=eval("[" + template + "]");
    for(var i=0; i<template.length; i++){
        result=template[i][1].search(new RegExp(keyword, "i"));
        if(result=="1"){
            resultsame+=template[i][1]+", ";
        }
        result="";
    }
    alert(resultsame);
}
```

I've tried the above code, but the problem is the code above just show one result

when I do a search with the keyword "a", it should be two, but the function that I make only displays one result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are limiting your result to only one with this line

```
if(result=="1"){
```

Result the position of where your keyword appears in the string.

I.e:

```
Search 'a' in 'Apple' -> 0        | Search 'to' in 'Potato' -> 4
```

When your keyword doesn't appear in the string, result will be `-1`

So change your line to:

```
if (result !== -1) {
```

Which will be true when a string matched.

See here for more details:
[JavaScript RegExp Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)